# Intellij build with an error alert but not showing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a java project in intellij on OS(mac) but the building window show error but can't specify the issue.[image]

Comment: In the Build Output window, on the bottom left, select the alert just above the one you have selected, where it is written "demo 2: build failed". It should have more information. I agree, this is unintuitive by Intellij

Comment: I have aleardy tried but it does not have more information.

Comment: Have you attempted to build on the command line?  My guess is that you're missing some libraries but I'll admit that it's weird that IntelliJ isn't giving you the error output.

Comment: I haven't tried with terminal yet. I doubt that I am missing any lib, I have created a simple spring boot project, but still can't run

Comment: Click on the little m to reload your pom.

Answer (score 0):

try to Reload maven or change JDK version 8 in your IDE